# java object creation using new operator and .class.newInstance() method

Tags: java, new-operator

I have following code snippet

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

Test test = null;
        try {
test = Test.class.newInstance(); 
if(test!=null)
                System.out.println("test class instance created");
            System.out.println(test.getA()+"\t"+test.getB());
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class Test {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("test class constructor executed");
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("static block of Test class exectuted");
    }


    {
        System.out.println("test class IIB executed");
    }
```

I am trying to create an instance of Test class using

```
test = Test.class.newInstance();
```

My Question: is this the correct way to do??

and also is there any difference between

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

and above approach?

I am getting following as when I run Test2 Class:

```
static block of Test class exectuted
test class IIB executed
test class constructor executed
test class instance created
0   0
```

Comment: Where did you read about `Test.class.newInstance(); `? Plus, is the output what you expect?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I was just trying to instantiate Test class object using above statement, 
Also when I use new operator also, I got the same output.

Comment: @LutzHorn, By using Test.class.newInstance(), I can see Test class has been loaded,static and instance initializer blocks are called followed by Test class constructor.
Also, same in case of new operator.

Answer (score 1):

> is this the correct way to do??

No, it is not. use `new`. Because [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

> Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler.